# Is the 'Ton an impossible shape?

Tags: deus-ex

In Deus Ex's Hell's Kitchen, it seems to me that there is an inconsistency in the 'Ton.

If you check your compass as you enter or exit the 'Ton through Paul's apartment window, I think you get transported to another side of the building. It's very weird, can anyone else see this?

Comment: I love Deus Ex.  I might have to set up an install just to confirm or deny your question :D

Comment: @LordScree As the saying goes... "Deus Ex.  Every time you mention it, SOMEONE will reinstall it". :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'Ton map has two exists, one is the main entrance and  the other is the Paul's apartment window.( fire escape )

When in outside map ( Hell's Kitchen ) and standing towards the main entrance, the window to Paul's apartment is at the right wall of the building.

But when you walk in the 'Ton map the window is in the wall directly in front of you.

Yes, the 'Ton map is incorrect with regards to the outside map and  is also 2-3 times larger than it should be.

Comment: So that's a yes, then?

Comment: @Asad Well the question is a little vague. What is "an impossible shape" really? I explained that the 'Ton map ( inside ) does not fit in the New York map ( outside )

Comment: I think the question is actually whether space loops back on itself in the map (ie you get transported between two non adjacent points on the map when moving through a certain place). The fact you brought up about the map being larger than the building that houses it is interesting too.